# Monotonic and bounded sequences throughout computer science

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, constructive-mathematics, analysis-of-algorithms

When I refer to the Monotone Convergence Theorem below, I refer to the very simple claim that if a non-decreasing sequence has an upper bound then it converges. I don't refer to the claim from Measure Theory.

One application I know of for this result is to recurrence relations. One shows that a recurrence relation like $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_n}, a_0 = 0$ is non-decreasing and bounded, from which one concludes that it has a limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Are there any other applications of the theorem?

I ask because I'm curious about the possibility of systematically "constructivising" applications of this theorem. Obviously in general this isn't possible. But surely there are lots of situations in which it may be possible.

By constructivise, I mean derive convergence bounds, and compute what the limit is explicitly.

I tried constructivising [Herschfeld's Convergence Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html), I believe successfully. The resulting argument is a great deal less straightforward than Herschfeld's original one.